# Channel Images Uncaught TypeError: $.base64Decode is not a function

Tags: safecracker, channel-images

I'm trying to use Channel Images in a front-end Channel Form situation. I have the channel images appearing, but the Upload Images button does not respond to clicking, and when I use the developer tools in Chrome, it spits out

Uncaught TypeError: $.base64Decode is not a function

and then a series of this information:

ChannelImages.ActivateUploadHandlers    @   channel_images_pbf.js?v=5.4.19:112

(anonymous function)    @   channel_images_pbf.js?v=5.4.19:68
n.extend.each   @   jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
n.fn.n.each @   jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
ChannelImages.InitFields    @   channel_images_pbf.js?v=5.4.19:64
ChannelImages.Init  @   channel_images_pbf.js?v=5.4.19:18
(anonymous function)    @   channel_images_pbf.js?v=5.4.19:1822
H.Callbacks.d   @   ?ACT=10&ui=core,widget,mouse,position,draggable,resizable,sortable,button,dialog,tabs,datepicker&pl…:16
H.Callbacks.p.fireWith  @   ?ACT=10&ui=core,widget,mouse,position,draggable,resizable,sortable,button,dialog,tabs,datepicker&pl…:16
s.extend.ready  @   ?ACT=10&ui=core,widget,mouse,position,draggable,resizable,sortable,button,dialog,tabs,datepicker&pl…:16
F.addEventListener.a    @   ?ACT=10&ui=core,widget,mouse,position

If I can't use channel images to upload via Channel Form, does anyone else have a suggestion for a clean, multiple file upload option for Channel Form?

Comment: Hi did you ever find a solution for this , I have exactly the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Late to answer this, but when I expirienced same problem it appeared to originate from fact that jQuery was also included second time in the footer. I removed jQuery inclusion from the footer and all started working.